# Where do i get BIOS.h file, to import in Mingw?

Tags: c, sys

Mingw don't have BIOS.h file by default. And i'm doing system programming by using netbeans IDE and a third party tool mingw. . ?

Can any one helps me, where do i get that file?

This is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<BIOS.H>
#include<DOS.H>

char st[80] ={"Hello World$"};

void main()
{
    _DX = (unsigned int) st;
    _AH = 0x09;
    geninterrupt(0x21);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Nowhere, you don't.

Those header files (`dos.h` and `bios.h`) are from 16-bit DOS compilers such as Turbo C or Open Watcom C. MinGW is a 32-bit compiler for Windows. As such, even if you get these header files, they will be useless because:

1. they are incompatible with gcc
2. they also need counterpart libraries because the headers themselves do not contain definitions of things like `geninterrupt()`
3. DOS interrupt services (`int 21h`) are not available to Win32 programs

Further, gcc does not support variables aliasing to CPU registers (e.g. `_DX`, `_AH`).

You either need to use the appropriate 16-bit DOS compiler or write a Windows program using functionality available from gcc and Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks you so much. you solved my problem. Yea you said right mingw is a 32-bit compiler. And it doesn't support bios level instructions.
And even i tried to copy bios.h file from Turbo c++ include folder and copy c:/mingw/include. it didn't work.

Comment: If any one encountered with such a problem. you have to use Turbo c++ for bios level instructions. Mingw doesn't support bios.h.
This is a link you can download turbo c for windows 7, vista 32 or 64 bit operating system. http://www.megaleecher.net/Download_Turbo_For_Windows

Comment: @qasimazam: No!  Using Turbo C++ is *not* the appropriate action- Unless you want to go back 20 years!  Rather you should replace the BIOS call with a suitable Win32 or standard library call. Moreover Int21 is a *DOS* not a BIOS call; 0x09 is "write string".  In Windows even with a 16 bit compiler, the call will be virtualised, trapped and converted to a Win32 console call, so any perceived efficiency in making the DOS call is false.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need it? It's been obsoleted a hundred or so times. But from what I've heard, some older Turbo C versions might have it. You can also try out http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/ , but they say the file might not have all the functions.

Comment: Yea i have to use turbo c, for bios level programming. Mingw doesn't support bios level instructions. bdw Thank you for the assistance